# Get vertical scroll position in Poltergeist

Tags: phantomjs, capybara, poltergeist

I'm writing a test that verifies the page scrolls back to the top when a certain action is performed. I'm using Capybara/Cucumber/Selenium/Poltergeist.
I have a working implementation for Selenium that uses

```
page.execute_script("return $('body').scrollTop()")
```

to evaluate the vertical scroll position, but this returns nil in Poltergeist. I've launched the inspector and Poltergeist returns 0 when I execute the line in the console. I've also tried

```
return document.documentElement.scrollTop()
```

but no luck. Is there an accepted way to check the vertical scroll in Poltergeist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

page.execute_script doesn't return a value (it happens to in the selenium driver if you use return, but that is a bug since the capybara docs specifically say it doesn't return a value - [capybara docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FSession%3Aexecute_script)).  What you want to use is

```
page.evaluate_script("$('body').scrollTop()")
```

Comment: I was using execute_script based on the reasoning [here.] (http://makandracards.com/makandra/12317-capybara-selenium-evaluate_script-might-freeze-your-browser-use-execute_script) I didn't realize it was Selenium specific. Thank you!

Comment: That may have been valid 3 years ago when it was posted, but today -- if you don't want a returned value use #execute_script - if you want a returned value use #evaluate_script